# negative time difference in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * , unix_timestamp( NOW( ) ) - unix_timestamp( created ) AS timedif  FROM is_meeting_comments WHERE meeting_id_fk=9
```

This query is used to find out the time difference between when the record was created (CURRENT TIMESTAMP) and when the select query is executed.

This query is return negatives values on remote PC's. While this problem is not apparent when I first tested on my local server. Is this because of different time zones set? But how would this matter, the time should be the same regardless of any PC because its being calculated from the server end.

[image]

Why are negative values occurring?

Comment: @Chris is pointing you in the right direction. Besides that you could consider using a timestamp datatype for your created column instead of a datetime.

Comment: @eddy I am already using timestamp datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that it is negative because of timezone differences. The `unix_timestamp` function assumes the argument is in a local time zone so it will convert it to UTC as part of its conversion process. If "created" is stored as a local time (non UTF) on a pc in a different timezone (or one with a different timezone configured) then the conversion could be off when read back in on a system in a different timezone.

MYSQL can be configured to allow per-connection timezones (so the timezone is the user's timezone, not the database server's timezone) and this can impact the way dates are stored. Check out [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) page for more details.